# How to use a terminal command's output in my program?

Tags: c, command-line, redirect, pipe

I want to parse the output of the command `w` for use in my program
I know i can execute `w` using `execlp` but is there a way to get the output from w into my program directly? I'm thinking i could use a pipe or something, but I don't know very much about it or how pipes work in an execlp command.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [popen(3)](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/popen/):

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
 char *command="w";
 FILE *fpipe = (FILE*)popen(command,"r")) );
 char line[256];
 while ( fgets( line, sizeof(line), fpipe))
 {
  printf("%s", line);
 }
 pclose(fpipe);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at `popen` for a simple way to do that, although it has various weaknesses (calling out to the shell, for example).  [libslack](http://libslack.org/) also has a `popen` replacement (the coprocess functions); it is under the GPL.

Answer (score 0):

man popen

(some other random characters to get past lame filter)

Comment: "RTFM" type answers are the reason the "lame filter" exists.